JMeter HTTP Request Path left empty after SSO
New to JMeter and trying to make a HTTP Request. Here is an overview of my Thread Group:

My HTTP Header Manager has the basic auth. Then My First HTTP Request has the Server or IP filled with "myproject.domain.com". Also, the Path is something like "/api/doSomething". When I run, I get a 200 response code. Judging from the response data, it looks like it did make it to my root page with SSO successfully passed (I verified this by changing my basic auth to random value, then received messages in the response data regarding unauthenticated). However, when I look at my View Results Tree, the Path has nothing but a slash somehow, instead of the "/api/doSomething" I want to test in the Path in My First HTTP Request:

Did the value get lost after the redirect to the SSO? Or any idea how I can make the API call? Any help is appreciated

Most probably your request is not properly configured, i.e. you're using incorrect method or you're being redirected somewhere.
Instead of configuring HTTP Request samplers manually you could record your test scenario using HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder or JMeter Chrome Extension. Of course in the majority of cases correlation will be required  but at least the nature of the requests will be realistic.

I think I made a silly mistake using GET instead of POST. Seems to be working now. Currently, it received the 301 Moved Permanently error but could be due to other issues.
